# Redeclaring variables in functions

Tags: swift, scope

Why does **redeclaring** `output` inside this if-statement **not generate an error?**

```
let output = 0
if counter < message.count {
    let output = counter //This should throw an error, right?
    counter += 1
} ...
```

The scope inside the if-statement knows about `output` as proven here, when trying to change the value of `output` instead of re-declaring it:

```
let output = 0
    if counter < message.count {
        output = counter //ERROR: Cannot assign to value: 'output' is a 'let' constant
        counter += 1
    } ...
```

Comment: I'd like to know why the "Hidden Local Variables" build setting, when enabled, doesn't flag cases like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error because it is perfectly legal to declare a variable inside a closure with the same name of a variable which has been declared outside of the closure. It shadows the "outside declared variable".

In case your sample code is inside a `class` you could still access the "outside declared variable" using `self`:

```
class Foo {
    let output = 0
    func baa() {
        let output = 1
        print(output)
        print(self.output)
    }
}
```

Using this:

```
let foo = Foo()
foo.baa()
```

prints:

```
1
0
```

Comment: So I have a choice of either defining a variable with the same name and then only accessing the outside variable via .self.
Or not defining a variable with the same name and being able to access the outside variable without having to use .self?

Comment: Okay thank you so much! Although I don't understand why they would design the language like that?

Comment: That's the way it works in many languages (Java, C, C++, Objective-C, Swift, Kobalt...). Dealing with scopes.

Answer (score 1):

`let output = counter` is declaring a new variable (output) in the scope of the `if` statement, which has nothing to do with the `output` variable declared outside.

**Edit**

The code extract below illustrates that the `output` variables are not the same, despite their name. The value that gets changed is the one of the local `output` variable, not the one outside.

```
var message = [String]()

let output = 2
var counter = -1
if counter < message.count {
    let output = counter //This should throw an error, right?
    print("local output value is:\(output)") // here the local output value is -1 not 2.
    counter += 1
}
```

Comment: But then why could I change the `output` variable (the one that was define outside of the if-statement) **inside** the if-statement?

Comment: You can access the "Output" (that was define outside of the if-statement) like this : self.Output

Comment: @Marmelador now with the change you have made in the question there is only one `output` variable, i.e. the one declared before the `if`. And the error is because of using `let` instead of `var` when declaring `output`. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

The first example is a case of [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).  This occurs when the code has multiple scope blocks. In the first example:

```
let output = 0  //outer scope block
if counter < message.count {
    let output = counter //inner scope block
    counter += 1
} ...
```

In the inner scope block, a new 'output' constant has been declared with the 'let' keyword.  That output constant is only valid within that 'if' block.  It happens to use the same name as the one declared above the "if" statement.  This is variable shadowing.

For the second example:

```
let output = 0
if counter < message.count {
    output = counter //ERROR: Cannot assign to value: 'output' is a 'let' constant
    counter += 1
} ...
```

The error is occurring because defining something with 'let' makes it a constant.  It cannot be changed. In this case there is only one 'output' constant. It was declared above the if statement and it is a constant.  So, it cannot be changed once it has been assigned a value.

So, in the first example, there are 2 "output" constants, one of which is only valid within the "if" statement.  In the second example, there is only 1 "output" constant.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces constitute a scope. In an inner scope, it is always legal to overshadow a variable name from an outer scope.

```
let output = // ... [A]
[class, func, if, for, do, etc.] {
    let output = // ... [B, overshadows A]
    // *
}
```

You've done a self-limiting thing, in one sense, in that code at the `*` point may now be unable to refer to `output` A; it is overshadowed by `output` B. But it isn't illegal. On the contrary, this is an important thing to be able to do, and to disallow it would be silly.